# Running psql with pgAdmin4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I try to open a csv file in PGadmin4 with COPY.
However it does not work.
The permission is denied and suggests me to use \copy from pgsql.

I tried to replace COPY by \copy, did not work.

I guess that pgsql must be run another way. I saw there [,example with \copy,](http://www.kevfoo.com/2012/01/Importing-CSV-to-PostGIS/) that it run with a shell file .sh. However I'm using Windows.

How to run pgsql request ?

Thank you

Comment: The title is inaccurate - you're not trying to run psql with pgadmin4

Comment: Yes I do, but I don't know how. If you say this because of my first lines, that was to explain the context.

Comment: psql is a program. You don't run psql through pgadmin. That simply makes no sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `Import/Export` option in pgAdmin4 to import your CSV data into Table.

Ref: https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/dev/import_export_data.html

Comment: Waow that works ! Great ! Then I do not need to use pgsql anymore. That way is pretty simple and I didn't found it before. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I answer you on my own question page. Yes, psql is the SQL Shell program and you could start it from the Postgresql folder (from where you start pgAdmin). You do not need of psql if you use pgAdmin.

Comment: I understand better now. Thank you for your clarification.